# Is it possible to get the size of a Flash video [YouTube] using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, youtube, video-streaming, bitrate

I would like to know the size of the movie I am watching on any video site [ *if not possible on all video sites, then at least on YouTube* ]. So is it possible, `say I will specify the complete path like: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xyuX7u-Xts'` , to calculate the size of the [Flash video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video) (.flv) using JavaScript?

**Note**
*By saying size I meant filesize, not the dimension. Sorry if it was creating any ambiguity. [ @cristoph ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Look for the [content-length in the header](http://phpjs.org/functions/filesize:401) with an XmlHttpRequest if you're looking to find out the .swf filesize.

**Edit**: If you're looking for the actual video size that gets streamed to your computer and not the just the player's filesize, you probably will have to do a little estimation. Take the [total bitrate](http://chadvonnau.com/youtube.html) in kbits per second for the video and multiply it by the number of seconds of the video length, which is available in the video page javascript source:

```
yt.setConfig({
//... (snip)
   'SWF_ARGS': {..., "length_seconds": "727", ...}
//... (snip)
}
```

Hope this helps get you started.